# upload picture to and send path to database

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload picture and link it to my database and I used the codes below :

Upload3.php

```
        <?php
    // Check if a file has been uploaded
    if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
        // Make sure the file was sent without errors
        if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'fyp');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            // Gather all required data
            $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
            $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
            $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
            $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

            // Create the SQL query
            $query = "
                INSERT INTO `pic` (
                    `Name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
                )
                VALUES (
                    '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
                )";

            // Execute the query
            $result = $dbLink->query($query);

            // Check if it was successfull
            if($result) {
                echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
                   . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
               . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
        }

        // Close the mysql connection
        $dbLink->close();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
    }

        // Echo a link back to the main page
        echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';


 ?>
```

and this is the form.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload3.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="uploaded_file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I reached the last stage and its give error a file was not sent

I don't know where I have missed.

thank you

Comment: Do you use right enctype? like `<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">` in you form

Comment: debug with: `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: the form is there already :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your form file name to "uploaded_file". You're script is looking for a non existent file post by the name of "file" rather than "uploaded_file"

Comment: Can you update your question form html so we can just make sure what you've changed is what we expected to be changed...

Answer (score 0):

Check the file name: `Upload2.php` or `upload3.php`? (careful case-insensitive). Change the `name="file"` to `name="uploaded_file"`.

**form.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="uploaded_file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In `upload2.php`, you forgot the `mime` field:

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

// Create the SQL query
$query = "
    INSERT INTO `pic` (
        `Name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
    )
    VALUES (
        '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', '{$datetime}'
    )";
```

Comment: @opa.mido I edited my answer. Try, but put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: is $datatime = date ("Y-m-d h:i:s"); adding to // Gather all required data??